# Android In App Billing v3: get prices doesn't work for unmanaged items

Tags: android, billing, in-app-purchase

I am using the standard Android IAB v3 code to detect prices of items at startup.

However it is not returning any SkuDetails for my unmanaged items, only for the managed items.

Any ideas?

```
static IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener()
{
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result,
            Inventory inventory)
    {
        if (result.isFailure())
        {
            return;
        }

        for (String sku : new String[]
        { "unmanaged_item1", "managed_item1" })
        {
            if (inventory.hasDetails(sku))
            {
                SkuDetails details = inventory.getSkuDetails(sku);
                Log.d(TAG, sku + ": " + details.getTitle() + "," + details.getPrice());
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> In Version 3, all in-app products are managed

http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html#consume

Comment: Ah thats interesting - so at the moment my iap list contains unmanaged and managed products (entered via the old developer console). Should I change them all to managed and then only consume the ones in code that used to be unmanaged?

Comment: Doing exactly that thanks - will have to use new sku's as I can't reuse the old - but no biggie.